# how to convert a daylight and a standard time to both standard time

Tags: r

I have the 2 dates below both are in **Pacific Time** but one of them is Daylight savings (PDT) and 1 is standard time (PST).

First question: How can I convert both to the PST?

Second question: How can I convert both to the EST-eastern standard time (`tz=America/New_York`), which is not the Eastern daylight time?

```
date= as.POSIXct(c("2016-04-01 15:30:00 PDT","2016-12-06 16:00:00 PST"))
date
## [1] "2016-04-01 15:30:00 PDT" "2016-12-06 16:00:00 PST"
```

Comment: `attr(date, "tzone") <- "EST"` doesn't work?

Comment: @ike - `date` becomes `[1] "2016-04-01 17:30:00 EST" "2016-12-06 19:00:00 EST"` on my machine, which is the correct conversion.

Comment: fair enough, submit that as well then? I've been so locked into lubridate I thought attr just overwrote didn't update, shows what I know.

Answer (score 0):

quite simple really. with Lubidridate as [documented here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html):

```
library(lubridate)

corrected_date <- force_tz(date,tz = "America/New_York")
```

Comment: How can you specifiy that it is America/New_York EST vs. EDT?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the tz= part.  that should do it.

Comment: and to make them both pst it's simply tz = 'PST'

Comment: quick! to the google machines!  run OlsonNames() and you'll get a list of valid names. I believe you might be searching for "PST8PDT"